# How do I see an object's references in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to understand Ruby's very subtle implementation of pass-by-value ... or really pass-by-reference-by-value. This makes sense when passing arguments to a method, however when I come across the following, I'm a little confused:

```
person = {name: "Michael"}
# => {:name => "Michael"}

person.object_id 
# => 70366412279760

full_name = person[:name]
# => "Michael"
full_name.object_id
# => 70366412279780

full_name << " Jordan"
# => "Michael Jordan"

person
# => {:name => "Michael Jordan"}
```

How is this possible? How does full_name contain a reference to the person object? Is there a method in Ruby where you can "see" a variable's references?

I've taken for granted writing code like above in the past but now that I'm trying to further understand what's going on, I'm stumped.

Comment: It's all about `binding`. Take a look here for starters - http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Binding.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`full_name` refers to a string object (which is also referred to by `person[:name]`). Calling `<<` on it modifies that string object rather than reassigning something to a variable named `full_name`.

`full_name` by itself does not carry the information that its referent is the value for `:name` in the hash `person`. It just happens that `full_name` and `person[:name]` point to the same object (id).

Comment: Ohhh ... I didn't see that. That makes sense!  That's why full_name.object_id is the same as person[:name].object_id ... THANK YOU!